# how to disable keys in OS X?

Tags: macos, keyboard-hook

I've an application that needs disable some keys while the application in running (i.e: A, option, command, shift).

how can I do that?

the language or method used does not matter.

Comment: Capture and consume the key events?

Answer (score 1):

You can inspect, modify, and block keyboard events with a [`CGEventTap`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html).

The user will need to grant your app assistive privileges via the Security pane of System Preferences for events to be disabled before posting.

Something like this:

```
- (void)setKeyBlocker {
    // You should filter this better than kCGEventMaskForAllEvents, depending on your needs.
    CFMachPortRef eventTap = CGEventTapCreate(kCGHIDEventTap, kCGHeadInsertEventTap, kCGEventTapOptionDefault, kCGEventMaskForAllEvents, cgEventCallback, NULL);

    CFRunLoopSourceRef runLoopSource = CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(kCFAllocatorDefault, eventTap, 0);
    CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), runLoopSource, kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
    CGEventTapEnable(eventTap, true);

    CFRelease(eventTap);
    CFRelease(runLoopSource);
}

CGEventRef callback(CGEventTapProxy proxy, CGEventType type, CGEventRef cgEvent, void *refcon) {
    NSEvent *event = [NSEvent eventWithCGEvent:cgEvent];

    if (event.type == kCGEventKeyDown) {
        if ([event.characters isEqualToString:@"a"]) {
            // Kill event
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    return cgEvent;
}
```